# static variable used with != operator and that too not in if or any loop condition

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  static int var;

  var!=0;
  var+=1;
  printf("Static value is :%d\n",var);
  return 0;
}
```

In this above code what exactly does `var!=0` do? And if it returns anything, what does it returns?

Comment: What's the connection to LINUX?

Comment: i m compiling with gcc that is why i put linux...

Comment: I'd ask the person who wrote the code what it does. And they will not be able to give you a correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

`var!=0` does nothing, except for comparison, which is not stored or used in any other way . It should be something like this if used for comparison, but it does not use the result of the comparison:

```
 if (var!=0)
 {
     // do something here
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `var` is declared static, its value is set to zero as it is created.
so the comparison `var!=0` returns false. however there is nothing to hold the result and the result will be lost. execution will just move forward to next line.

Answer (score 0):

It checks if the values of two operands are equal or not, if values are not equal then condition becomes true.

Answer (score 0):

The static variable `var` is auto initialized to 0.

The code

```
var != 0;
```

Will do the comparisons and check if `var` is not equal to 0 and will return `false`, but it is not stored anywhere and nothing is done to it, so it won't cause any effect to the program.

So, a statement like that would do nothing other than waste some precious time since the return value is not even stored anywhere or used in some way.

The next code

```
var += 1;
```

increases `var` to 1 and you then print out the value.